# rails rescue_from ScriptError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, ruby-2.2

According to the family tree of Exception. `SyntaxError` is child to `ScriptError`

I wish to handle Syntax and/or ScriptError in my rails application.

```
Exception
    NoMemoryError
    ScriptError
        LoadError
        NotImplementedError
        SyntaxError
    SignalException
        Interrupt
    StandardError
        ArgumentError
        IOError
            EOFError
        IndexError
            StopIteration
        LocalJumpError
        NameError
            NoMethodError
        RangeError
            FloatDomainError
        RegexpError
        RuntimeError
        SecurityError
        SystemCallError
        SystemStackError
        ThreadError
        TypeError
        ZeroDivisionError
    SystemExit
    fatal
```

---

I did:

`rescue_from ScriptError, :with => :notify_on_landing_page`

but didn't worked.

Error raised on screen : 
`SyntaxError in Bc::Muse::User::ProfileController#show`

I have created an explicit syntax error, it should gracefully rescue it and do the things I want to.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think it works that way.

Rescuing from exceptions with `rescue_from` works **only after creating a controller instance during request processing** (see source code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb#L30) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L237)). Your `SyntaxError` is probably raised much earlier - during autoloading of the given controller and dependent classes / modules. So unless you were trying to rescue from a syntax error of code being loaded *during* a controller action execution, you are out of luck, I'm afraid.

**Test:** when you explicitly `load` a file with a syntax error in a controller action and the `rescue_from` will work as expected:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from(::SyntaxError) { Rails.logger.error "SYNTAX ERROR!" }

  def index
    load "#{Rails.root}/test.rb"
  end
end
```

If you save a `test.rb` file in the rails root and add a deliberate syntax error in it, you will see the exception is handled correctly by `rescue_from` and the error message will be present in the log file.

On the other hand, if you look at the full stack trace of your `SyntaxError`, you will probably see that it does not even reach the `ActionController` methods for request processing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

I added a middleware to achieve this.

```
class RescueSyntaxError
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  rescue SyntaxError => error

    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    session = request.env['rack.session']
    params = request.params

    if session.try(:[], :user_object)
      ##Do validation stuff
      ...
      [302, {'Location' => '/'}, []]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, interesting. Does it work even in production environment? I thought Rails eager loads all files upon starting in production so at first thought I'd expect this to work in development only. But am not sure.